# Github API cannot read the '#' in the file path but need to change to '%'

Tags: python, github, github-api

I was trying to get the file content from `Github API`,I found out that when we put the `file_path` as `service-#abcd-P#1234.json`, it returned as not found but when I changed to `service-%abcd-P%1234.json`, it was able to retrieve the content of the file

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{username}/{repository_name}/contents/{file_path}
```

So I would like to ask if there is any more way to overcome this issue as `file_path` is automatically generated by the system

changed the `#` in `file_path` to `%`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL and read chapter "syntax" and then read about "url encoding"

Comment: Moreover, you're already wrong if you aren't URL encoding everything.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote